# How to address missing values in Pearson Correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, missing-data, pearson-r

I am working on Pearson Correlations and for each individual I have at least one missing data point. When I create the correlation matrix in R, I get NAs for each individual where a variable is missing. Is there a way to address that or a way around it? Is only using complete cases the appropriate choice? Or replacing missing values with the group mean?

Comment: Voting to close as this is probably an R problem. You need to handle missing data, R doesn't do it for you. The easiest is to say `cor(x, na.rm=T)`.

Comment: I think it's perfectly within the scope of Cross Validated to discuss approaches to handling missing data. For instance, removing the rows with missing observations is one option, and statistical theory discusses the disadvantages (smaller sample size, potential bias).

Comment: Use cor(x, use="pairwise.complete.obs")

Comment: You might want to look at [imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)). I have found Bayesian imputation quite flexible, which is nicely explained by Richard McElreath [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMiSb8GKR0o).